# Django PostgreSQL ForeignKey-Relation always throws error

Tags: django, postgresql

I switched from sqlite to PostgreSQL (in a django project). Everything worked in sqlite but in PostgreSQL are some errors. I tried to fix them and now I'm stuck in this error.

I have an article model and an image model (with a foreignkey relation to article).

```
class Image(models.Model):
    Article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Artikel")
```

When I try to migrate my database I get this error:

```
Key columns "image_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and integer.
```

I deleted my Image model and I tried to migrate the database but I get the same error.

Comment: can post Article model code

Comment: Did you create the database tables with migrations, or manually? Seems like you have a foreign key to image table, but that foreign key is of type varchar, whereas id field of image table is of type integer

Comment: @OzgurAkcali I created a database (manually) and then I used `manage.py migrate` and `manage.py makemigrations`
@c.grey What do you need? Article doesn't has any special values or any relation to Image model (except the Image to Article Foreignkey-Relation)